# Reverse a queue without using any extra space

Tags: data-structures, queue, reverse

I have an unsorted queue of certain elements. I want to reverse the queue but without using any extra space. Is there any method?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using recursion. you can follow the following steps to write the recursion function.

```
void reverseQ(queue q) 
{ 
    // 1) if queue is empty return
    // 2) pop out the front element from queue and save it into a variable
    // 3) call reverseQ(q)
    // 4) push the popped front element back to queue  
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort and yes that will work. But I mentioned that without using any space. And recursion uses the stack. I know we are not assigning from the user end but still, the computer assigns itself.